# PHP regex remove space in specific string

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to remove the " " (space) in the following string. Be aware that this is only part of a string (there are valid spaces in it just not this one). So the code should identify this string then remove the space.

**Example:**

```
18-Sep 00:20
```

**Test:**

```
/\d{1,2}-[a-z]{3}\s*( )\d{2}:\d{2}/
```

Comment: `Sep` has a capital so either use the `i` modifier or add `A-Z` to your character class.

Comment: Use the `i` flag to make your regex match case insensitive to match both `a-z` and `A-Z` (or add `A-Z` after `a-z`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or try

```
/(\d{1,2}-[A-Z][a-z]{2}) +(\d{2}:\d{2})/   // REGEXP
```

with

```
"$1$2"         // as the replacement string
```

This way the replacement will only affect string fragments with three digit month names, starting with a capital letter. It will also remove more than one blanks if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You might use lookarounds:

```
(?<=\w) (?=\d{2}:\d{2})
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/Bpmfd2/1).

---

Broken apart, this says:

```
(?<=\w)         # pos. lookbehind
\               # space
(?=\d{2}:\d{2}) # 00:11 format
```

Comment: I think.Nowadays it became fashion to downvote on anything. I have seen few people, who tried to downvote others answer, so that people can get attention toward his/her answer. BTW I didn't downvoted

Comment: Maybe because someone thinks your pattern is too loose? OP has date and "-" too.

Comment: Hey, just to put the record straight, I did not downvote either. I like your solution. It could be made a little tighter though.

Comment: @cars10m: It's not that I'm gonna weep myself to sleep, it's just a general observation I'm making.

Comment: Note that `(?<=\w)` before a space is strictly the same than `\b`. Whatever, since blackswan wrotes: *"the code should identify this string then remove the space"*, I think you should reuse elements of his pattern in particular the beginning; and instead of putting it in a lookbehind, I think it's more efficient (and more simple) to use the `\K` feature.

Comment: This answer changes the regular expression in a non-trivial way (and absolutely needlessly) such that it will match far more than the OP's specific needs or wants. On a technical level, it is a bad answer to the question. Also, there is *zero* explanation of the changes you've made, why you made them, and why the OP would want to adopt them. This sort of code-only answer, particularly for regex questions, more often than not hinders the OP and subsequent readers rather than helps.  On a helping level, it leaves much to be desired. That's "what's up".

Comment: @salathe: That is a good explanation to a downvote. To be honest, I was indeed a bit lazy when it comes to explaining/documenting. However, I disagree that it is a technically bad answer. Indeed, more input strings are needed to craft a good and well maintainable expression. One could even think of `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`, etc. but as of now finding out the *real* input format is just poking in the dark.